# positioning a CSS popup with javascript script

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

Here is a FIDDLE of what I want my popup to look like... this works well:
http://jsfiddle.net/mib92/x6yev5a0/
(both `display` are set to: `block;` ) and it shows perfectly.

When I run it in my code, I use a JS script to do the popup.

my HTML:

```
  <a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')">Click to Open CSS Pop Up</a> 

line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>line <br>

<!--POPUP-->    
<script type="text/javascript" src="css-pop.js"></script>

<div id="blanket" style="display:none;"></div>

<div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none;">
<a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')" class="popclose">Click to Close CSS Pop Up</a>
</div>  
<!-- END POPUP -->
```

MY CSS: (same as the FIDDLE without the `display: block;` because it is set to `display:none;` in the HTML)

```
#blanket {
background-color:#ff0024;
opacity: 0.65;
*background:none;
position:fixed;
z-index: 9001;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

#popUpDiv {
 position:fixed;
 background-color:#ccc;
 width:400px;
 height:400px;
 border:5px solid #000;
 z-index: 9002;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 margin-left: -200px;
 margin-top: -200px;    
}
```

And here is the JS CODE:

```
function toggle(div_id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(div_id);
    if ( el.style.display == 'none' ) { el.style.display = 'block';}
    else {el.style.display = 'none';}
}
function blanket_size(popUpDivVar) {
    if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
        viewportheight = window.innerHeight;
    } else {
        viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }
    if ((viewportheight > document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight) && (viewportheight > document.body.parentNode.clientHeight)) {
        blanket_height = viewportheight;
    } else {
        if (document.body.parentNode.clientHeight > document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight) {
            blanket_height = document.body.parentNode.clientHeight;
        } else {
            blanket_height = document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight;
        }
    }
    var blanket = document.getElementById('blanket');
    blanket.style.height = blanket_height + 'px';
    var popUpDiv = document.getElementById(popUpDivVar);
    popUpDiv_height=blanket_height/2-200;//200 is half popup's height
    popUpDiv.style.top = popUpDiv_height + 'px';
}
function window_pos(popUpDivVar) {
    if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
        viewportwidth = window.innerHeight;
    } else {
        viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }
    if ((viewportwidth > document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth) && (viewportwidth > document.body.parentNode.clientWidth)) {
        window_width = viewportwidth;
    } else {
        if (document.body.parentNode.clientWidth > document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth) {
            window_width = document.body.parentNode.clientWidth;
        } else {
            window_width = document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth;
        }
    }
    var popUpDiv = document.getElementById(popUpDivVar);
    window_width=window_width/2-200;//200 is half popup's width
    popUpDiv.style.left = window_width + 'px';
}
function popup(windowname) {
    blanket_size(windowname);
    window_pos(windowname);
    toggle('blanket');
    toggle(windowname);     
}
```

My understanding of the JS code is that the `#blanket` and the `#popUpDiv`  change the `display:none;` to `display:block;` ... but the popup doesn't position at the proper place like in the Fiddle ?  I have no idea why... there must be something in the JS that causes this... because the HTML & CSS position the popup properly...  any ideas ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

oh, my... first of all, you should remove that from css:

```
margin-left: -200px;
margin-top: -200px;
```

then replace that:

```
popUpDiv_height=blanket_height/2-200;//200 is half popup's height
```

with that:

```
popUpDiv_height=viewportheight/2-200;//200 is half popup's height
```

because blanket_height - it's the page's full height. And you need only viewport's height